# Edit System.Servicemodel values programmatically?

Tags: wcf, web-config

When using WCF, there is a section in the web.config as below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="abc">
        <endpoint /> <---this
      </service>
   </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Is it possible to edit the area I've marked programmatically?

I can see there is a sytem.serviceModel namespace, but other than that I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change these parameters at runtime you can override ServiceHost.OnOpening()
E.g. to change port:

```
protected override void OnOpening()
{
    foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in Description.Endpoints)
    {
        string uriString = string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}{3}",
            endpoint.Address.Uri.Scheme,
            endpoint.Address.Uri.Host,
            endpoint.Address.Uri.Port + _basePort,
            endpoint.Address.Uri.LocalPath);

        endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(uriString);
    }

    base.OnOpening();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement Mike Mozhaev's answer, since your service is hosted in IIS you'll need a `ServiceHostFactory` to get a reference to the service host (or to use your own host). There's some information about it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx.